# how to drag , move , elongate object in blender on mac

Tags: geometry

I have installed blender for  making small logo . I have no prior idea of blender . The challenge i am facing is only PC i have is mac.

I am facing problem in moving  , dragging deleting objects on blender + mac.
As i do right click on cube( selected object)  in upper right window hierarchy , i m unable to see delete option. But on windows it shows delete  option in pop up menu.

Also , i m facing problem in changing shape of object ... i don't use mouse . Can  some one help me with the menu option where i can set length  width height of any object selected .

Please help .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you watch a video tutorial series .  Here is one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw   [].  This site is not focused on tutorials.  Please take the time to clarify your statement. I find your problem statement unclear.  Others may find it clear.  I do not currently operate on a Mac.  The [delete] object  also on the menu bar.  You might consider temporarily borrowing or buying an economical mouse if your mouse does not operate as expected.  You stated [click] and then stated [don't use mouse],   so I find that difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac Book Pro in the Blender “Outliner” move your cursor with the scratch pad over an object and while pressing “Command” and then clicking the scratch pad will open a drop down menu with options including “Delete”.

[image]

With your cursor in the 3D Viewport pressing “N” will toggle on and off transform options. In “Object Mode” move your cursor to an object in the 3D viewport and then while pressing the “Command” key click the object with the scratch pad to select it. Then hover your cursor over the appropriate Transform input field and click in it with the scratch pad. You can then enter numeric values to make changes in your object.

[image]